# bash echo display with tabs

Tags: bash, tabs, echo

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo  -e "dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd\tdd"
echo  -e "dzdddddddddd\tdd"
echo  -e "dzddddddd\tdd
```

Why i have this : 
output

```
dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd   dd
dzdddddddddd    dd
dzddddddd       dd
```

and not :

```
dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd   dd
dzdddddddddd                            dd
dzddddddd                               dd
```

I want the last output if it possible with echo, Thanks for the help

Comment: Does it really need to be with `echo`?  There are better tools for the job than that

Comment: AFAIK, it is displaying correctly only *one* tab. If you use only one `\t`, then the longer line will display the next string farther away than the shorter lines. Tabs kind of divide the display in columns, and only goes as far as the to the nearest "column" space. You second and third lines illustrate this well, they both go to the same "column" space

Comment: It would be a terminal-specific feature to have explicit tab stops, rather than assuming tab stops every *n* columns.

Answer (score 3):

If your terminal supports it, there is some support for setting tab stops manually. (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46368/set-tab-width-in-gui-terminal.) For example, assuming the default tab stops are already in place:

```
echo -e "dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd\t$(tput tbc; tput hts)dd"
echo -e "dzdddddddddd\tdd"
echo -e "dzddddddd\tdd"
```

produces

```
dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd   dd
dzdddddddddd                            dd
dzddddddd                               dd
```

`tput tbc` clears all existing tab stops. `tput hts` creates tab stops every *n* columns if the cursor is currently in column *n*. Since `\t` is used before `tput tbc` in the example above, it uses the preexisting tab stops, which are probably every 8 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf '%-37s   %2s\n' dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd dd
printf '%-37s   %2s\n' dzdddddddddd dd
printf '%-37s   %2s\n' dzddddddd dd
```

37 is the length of the longest string. You can get it by

```
s=dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
echo ${#s}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `column`:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
  echo -e "dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd\tdd"
  echo -e "dzdddddddddd\tdd"
  echo -e "dzddddddd\tdd"
} | column -s $'\t' -t
```

From `man column`:

> `-s`: Specify a set of characters to be used to delimit columns for the -t option.
>
> `-t`: Determine the number of columns the input contains and create a table.  Columns are delimited with whitespace, by default, or with the characters supplied using the -s option. Useful for pretty-printing displays.

Output:

```
dzddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd  dd
dzdddddddddd                           dd
dzddddddd                              dd
```